# SARIMA model on original (unstable variability) or transformed (stabilized) series?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, variance-stabilizing

If my series requires a log-transformation to stabilize variability, do I apply the `sarima` function to the log-transformed series or the original series? Does the same apply to the `auto.arima` function?

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

You need well-behaved model residuals for the estimators of the model parameters to be well behaved. You need well-behaved estimators for sound hypothesis testing and reliable forecasting. Therefore, in the context of (S)ARIMA models you would like your model residuals to resemble an i.i.d. series.

Note that you do not depend as much on the behaviour of the original data as you depend on the behaviour of the residuals. However, behaviour of the original data can admittedly indicate problems even before you fit the model.

If you skip the log-transformation and your model residuals do resemble an i.i.d. series, you are fine. If they don't, you can try applying the log-transformation *before* fitting the model. If your residuals become well behaved, you are fine. If not, the results of your hypothesis testing and/or forecasting may be poor.

Note also that there is no point in applying a transformation to model residuals *after* fitting the model. That will not improve the model.